# What is the maximum number of jars the factory can produce ? (no two jars are the same)

Tags: combinatorics

This question is from an intro to probability course, and while I have the solution, I felt the explanation was lacking so I'm hoping for someone to help understand how one arrives at the answer.

Question:

A candy factory has an endless supply of `red, orange, yellow, green, blue, black, white, and violet jelly beans`.

The factory packages the jelly beans into jars in such a way that each jar has

`200 beans`, `equal number of red and orange beans`, `equal number of yellow and green beans`,`one more
black bean than the number blue beans`, and `three more violet beans than the number of white
beans`.

One possible color distribution, for example, is a jar of 50 yellow, 50 green, one black,
48 white, and 51 violet jelly beans. `As a marketing gimmick, the factory guarantees that no
two jars have the same color distribution. What is the maximum number of jars the factory can
produce?`

Using basic algebra I was able to get this point:

$x + y + z + v = 98$

So it seems I need to figure out all the ways these 4 variables can add up to to 98.

At first I was thinking ${98 \choose 4}$ , but apparently this is wrong.

The correct solution is  ${101 \choose 3}$

Can someone help me understand the solution (remember this is an intro class, so I probably won't be familiar with more advanced concepts)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you clear away the complications, as you have, the 4-way partition of $98$ can be regarded as inserting 3 dividers into a set of 98, which indicate the place where the colour changes. You can satisfy yourself that this accounts for all qualifying options.

This makes it a "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" problem.

The $101$ in the textbook answer of $\binom{101}{3}$ is the $98$ items plus the $3$ category dividers. Choosing $3$ is selecting where those dividers go.